# How to run Flutter web on intranet?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web, intranet

I try to use *Chrome (web-javascript)* on vs code to debug my application.

[image]

But *Chrome (web-javascript)* cannot connect to **the intranet**.

[image]

My app try to look up an internal route, but it cannot reach.

`final connection = await InternetAddress.lookup(internalRoute);`

*show error*

`Unsupported operation: InternetAddress.lookup`

How to fix this?

Comment: Cannot look up an internal route.

Comment: the exception show "Unsupported operation: InternetAddress.lookup"

Answer (score -1):

enter command 'git config --enable-web' on terminal
and try to do run flutter application.

Comment: Is it related to `git`?